# How can I mount a partition in the middle of a full disk image in userspace?

Tags: filesystems, mount, fuse

It is perfectly possible to mount a partition with a disk image using `mount` or `losetup`'s  "offset" parameter. However to mount an image in userspace without requiring root permission or setting up fstab etc, fuseiso is needed (I think).

Unfortunately fuseiso doesn't seem to have the offset parameter needed to reach into the image to the partition.

I'm not sure if I'm out of luck, or if there might be some trick to get it to work by perhaps producing some sort of phantom file that effectively starts at the offset of the other file (I don't want to make a copy, otherwise `dd` would do the trick).

### Use Case

My use case is building disk images on an autobuild server where the build job is not allowed to have root permissions, and the server should not need a custom setup for particular build jobs.

### TL;DR

- Can fuseiso reach into a full disk image (not just partition image)?
- If not, is it possible to create a file/link that into the middle of a file to fake out fuseiso?
- Is there another option besides fuseiso ?